# Spark HDFS size on AWS?

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs

I ran the `spark-ec2` script with `--ebs-vol-size=1000` (and the 1000GB volumes are attached) but when I run `hadoop dfsadmin -report` shows only:

```
Configured Capacity: 396251299840 (369.04 GB)
```

per node. How do I increase the space or tell HDFS to use the full capacity?

Comment: If it helps, I have provided a slightly elaborate answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33598301/spark-ec2-ebs-vol-size-not-working/34076229#34076229

Answer (score 0):

Run lsblk and see where the volume is mounted. It is probably vol0. In your hdfs-site.xml , add /vol0 to dfs.data.dir value  after comma to the existing default. Copy this to all slaves and restart cluster. You should see full capacity now