# spark-ec2 --ebs-vol-size not working

Tags: apache-spark

When launching a spark cluster with `spark-ec2`, the `--ebs-vol-size` flag appears to have no effect.  Setting it with `50` or `500` and then ssh'ing into the master node, a `df -h` shows about 10G of space on `/`.

**How can I use `spark-ec2` to create a larger EC2 virtual machine?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A bit elaborate list of steps have been provided below that worked for me -

1. Launch a spark-ec2 cluster with --ebs-vol-size
2. Shutdown hadoop on ./ephemeral-hdfs

   ./ephemeral-hdfs/bin/stop-all.sh
3. Start hadoop on ./persistent-hdfs

   ./persistent-hdfs/bin/start-all.sh
4. You can verify that the current size has not reflected the requested ebs vol size

   ./persistent-hdfs/bin/hadoop dfsadmin -report
5. Run the following commands ( recommend to put them into a script ) and run it -

   ./persistent-hdfs/bin/stop-all.sh

   sed -i 's#vol/persistent-hdfs#vol0/persistent-hdfs#g' ~/persistent-hdfs/conf/core-site.xml

   ./spark-ec2/copy-dir.sh ~/persistent-hdfs/conf/core-site.xml

   ./spark-ec2/copy-dir.sh ~/persistent-hdfs/conf/hdfs-site.xml

   ./persistent-hdfs/bin/hadoop namenode -format

   ./persistent-hdfs/bin/start-all.sh
6. Repeat Step 4 to verify size

Credits - 
[Gist Reference by brendancol](https://gist.github.com/brendancol/2edc09cacd5bff38fd7a)

Comment: Thanks this answer was very useful - one thing though - the gist reference in the provided link has been updated and works better than the commands provided above - maybe the answer could be updated to show the updated gist file?